# launch teamviewer by command line in android

Tags: android, command-line

I want to develop a app to be a third-party to launch teamviewer to get access to the target pc without typing in id and password. or in other words, to run the app by command line(launch it and pass the parameters). i know this can be done by windows, but i need to implement it in android.

And I have another problem that i still cannot execute command line by android code, my code is

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os= new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("adb shell\n");
os.writeBytes("am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile/com.teamviewer.remotecontrollib.activity.MainActivity");
```

Is this code right?

Comment: I reformatted the code but the last line is unclear.

Comment: thanks for help. i am a newbee here. any thoughts about the problem?

Comment: No sorry. Hopefully others.